# The “open-ended Irish backstop” (Brexit)

Tags: phrase-origin, headline-english, synecdoche

> Downing Street let it be known that May’s withdrawal agreement might after all be acceptable, if only the **open-ended Irish backstop** could be removed. Brussels in return let it be known that Johnson’s new Whitehall sherpa, David Frost, was in town, and that the backstop was the issue under discussion.
>   *[The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2019/aug/29/no-deal-brexit-boris-johnson-parliament)*

This excerpt is awashed in [metonymies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_metonyms); *Downing Street* refers to the appointed executive power in the UK; *May* is short for [Theresa May](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theresa_May#Appointment), the former Prime Minister of the UK; *Brussels* represents the European Parliament; *Johnson* refers to the current Prime Minister of the UK, Boris Johnson; *Whitehall* stands for Parliament, a *Sherpa* (*The Guardian* spells it lowercase) is a Himalayan mountain guide; maybe that last one is a metaphor.

But what is an ***Irish backstop***? Is that also a metonymy? A synecdoche? A euphemism? What?

The BBC has an [article](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-northern-ireland-politics-44615404) that explains what it means in a single sentence

> The **backstop** is a position of last resort, to maintain a seamless border on the island of Ireland.

But until Brexit, I had never heard of a *[backstop](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/backstop)* being applied to an inland border. *Lexico* (formerly Oxford Dictionaries) defines it as

> **1.** A thing placed at the rear of something as a barrier or support.
>   **1.3** An emergency precaution or last resort.

Online I found an infographic that uses the term, but it's enclosed in quotes, which suggests that the meaning might be unfamiliar or ambiguous.

[image]

Why is the solution by Brussel, which is meant to preserve the free movement of goods and people within Ireland, called a **backstop**? Since when? Did someone came up with this baffling term? And is the **Irish backstop** a metonymy, a metaphor, or something else?

Comment: I think it means what the graphic says it means: It's an "if all else fails" last resort proposal.

Comment: @Robusto I think you're right, it's a last minute policy or mechanism that falls in place if Britain doesn't organise itself in time. Oh... OK. I've been brushing up on my Brexit drama and I couldn't understand why the word *backstop* was used everywhere.

Comment: You're right.  "Backstop" is a metonym.  It's a metonym for a proposal or plan to *prevent* a hard border coming up between Ireland and Northern Ireland as a result of Brexit.  I believe it's called a "backstop" because its purpose is to prevent relations with between Ireland and Northern Ireland from reverting to what they were as recently as the 90s, which was extremely separatist and extremely violent. The Backstop is a backstop to keep the diplomatic ground they've gained with an open border and not backslide into what's depicted in movies like '71, starring Jack O'Connell.

Comment: @BenjaminHarmanBut  is *backstop* really a metonym though? I'm not sure it is.

Comment: I think so.  I mean, it's not in the US, but in the UK, it's a word used as a substitute for that policy, which doesn't rightly have a name, thus the reason this metonym has arisen.

Comment: This may wind up as an elusive angel-count on the head of a figurative pin, since we rhetoric lovers love nothing better than parsing and categorizing figures of speech.  Questions like this send me running to MH Abrams, who if not the ultimate authority, certainly has substantial street cred.  Following MHA's lead, I'd call *backstop* a metaphor rather than pursue a metonymic argument.  Great question, though!

Comment: Maybe a metaphor.  Maybe a metonym.  Maybe an elusive angels' split hair-count on the head of a figurative pin.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Someone will know the answer :) At least, I have better understood the issue concerning N.Ireland. I can *attempt* to explain it to my Italian family, friends and home students. That alone is a small victory!

Comment: Is using someone's surname a metonym?

Comment: Or is it one because out of all the possible Mays/Johnsons, it's obvious who they refer to?

Comment: @marcellothearcane I am not 100% sure myself, but it seems to me that the surname is used in place of their title. Nowadays we hear of "Trump" but before he was elected as President of the US, he was known as *The Donald*, a nickname  no longer used by the media.

Comment: This is fun - when you search 'backstop' with Google, click the little 'tools' box next to the icons, and you can specify a date range. All results up to 23 June 2016 are unrelated except one on the 7th (which has since been edited)

Comment: Consider that backstop is a word with a definition. Backstops come in many varieties. In baseball a screen behind the catcher is a backstop; it stops the ball if the catcher fails to catch it. It’s not a metonym or a metaphor or anything else. This particular backstop is modified by “Irish,” and thus made specific to the Brexit deal.

Comment: @Xanne  But *Irish backstop* is being used figuratively, it's not literally a baseball net that encompasses the entire island. It stands for a agreement. I'm thinking it's a metaphor. Until I searched on Google, in my imagination, a backstop was similar to a wedge.

Comment: @Cascabel it was about  N.Ireland being a sticking point in the Brexit woes. I couldn't quite get why it was such a big thing. As for the IRA, and acts of terrorism, I was living in London when the troubles were at their peak, and we studied a little Irish history at secondary school. I also watched Michael Collins, the movie, in Italy, good too.

Comment: @Cascabel  harrowing and senseless times.

Answer (score 2):

According the the OED, back-stop or backstop is defined as:

> a. Something placed at the back to serve as a barrier; spec. a mound
>   of earth or embankment set up behind a target on a rifle range. *Also
>   figurative.*
>
> 1851   F. Starr Twenty Years Trav. Life xiii. 143   The
>   remaining shaft..broke off short, and that which when we started was a
>   gig, was now a back stop for horses' heels.
>
> 1904   G. F. Goodchild & C. F. Tweney Technol. & Sci. Dict. 37/1   Back stops (Cotton Spinning), buffers, used to prevent the mule carriage from going beyond a certain point during its inward run.
>
> 1946   Sports Afield Jan. 55/1 (D.A.)   Put up two targets on the backstop for the second barrel practice.
>
> 1947   Landfall 1 43   This being the first issue of Landfall, there is no previous survey to provide a convenient back-stop to discussion.
>
> 1954   W. Faulkner Fable (1955) 343   The railroad embankment..would serve as a backstop for what bullets neither flesh nor wood absorbed.

This suggests that the word is used figuratively when there is no physical barrier (this entry not updated since 1973, though). Since then everyday use suggests it is losing it figurative connotation and become a more literal expression of a wide variety of situations.

The OED also reports the derivative use of backstop as a verb:

> backstop  v. transitive, to support, back up; to supply with necessary additional resources. colloquial (orig. and chiefly U.S.).
>
> 1977   N.Y. Times 17 June A26/2   The International Monetary Fund can backstop the private system.

Consider that *backstop* is a word with a definition. Backstops come in many varieties. In baseball a screen behind the catcher is a backstop; it stops the ball if the catcher fails to catch it. It’s not a metonymy or a metaphor or anything else. This particular backstop is modified by “Irish,” and thus made specific to the Brexit deal.

My neighbor can be my *backstop* for taking care of my kids in the event that I can’t find a babysitter. That’s not a metaphor; it’s the use of a word with a definition.

As broadcast on CSPAN-2 on September 1, 2019, from the National Archives, author Philip Mudd (*Black Site*) described the views of one of the terrorists (Kalid Sheikh Muhammad) on the importance of destroying the United States before destroying what he considers corrupt Arab regimes as follows:  "The Americans are the *backstop* to these corrupt regimes."

A last resort is not figurative. Neither is backstop. It seems to me, at least, that it’s literal, however complicated the conditions that trigger it and its actual provisions may be.

See also [this Ngram for backstop](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=backstop&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbackstop%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbackstop%3B%2Cc0), which shows that in the last 60 years, the word has been used in economics (especially energy and climate control research), insurance, and finance.

A good swr for a last resort would be backstop.

Comment: @Cascabel, I added an NGram link, which shows the use of the word in the fields of  finance, insurance, medicine, climate change, and energy.  Earlier uses, as well as current ones, relate to stopping bullets, arrows, balls, etc., and preventing trucks from backing up into whatever.  It's used as a noun, adjective, and verb.

Answer (score 0):

**backstop** a noun with the sense:  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/backstop)

> - a precaution in case of an emergency
>
>   - Type of:
>       guard, precaution, safeguard
>       a precautionary measure warding off impending danger or damage or injury etc.

With **backstop** as the noun, **Irish** is the adjective and current events place it in the Brexit scenario. It's a polito-legal device to prevent damage to a party(s) to the dispute

Earliest usage in print I could find:

*The Irish Yearbook of International Law*  [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=m290DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA63&dq=%22irish%20backstop%22&pg=PA63#v=onepage&q=%22irish%20backstop%22&f=false)  White Paper  2018

> ... removing customs checks and controls between the UK and EU so the
>   **Northern Irish backstop solution** would not be triggered.

More on **backstop**:

In AmE, backstop is frequently used as a verb, figuratively, but that is not the case in the EU situation. I believe we borrowed this sense of the verb from the Aussies.